# Git pre-receive hook automatically run unit tests being pushed in the current ref

Tags: git, unit-testing, githooks

I am having a problem in my flow, I setup a `pre-receive` hook to run unit tests for branches `master` and `dev` as following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        if [[ ${ref} = refs/heads/master ]];
        then
                BRANCH=master
                WORKING_DIR="/var/www/project/project_api"
        elif [[ ${ref} = refs/heads/dev ]]
        then
                BRANCH=dev
                WORKING_DIR="/var/www/project/project_api_dev"
        else
                echo "Ref $ref received. Will not run unit tests."
        fi
done

if (test "$BRANCH" != ""); then
        echo "Running Unit Tests..."
        cd "$WORKING_DIR"
        npm test
        rc=$?
        if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
                echo "Unit Tests FAILED"
                echo "Push is REJECTED"
                exit $rc
        fi

        echo "Unit Tests PASSED"
fi

exit 0
```

With this setup, I want to reject the push if one of the unit tests **(being pushed)** fail.

The issue is that it runs the tests that are already checked out to the working directory `$WORKING_DIR`, not the tests that are being pushed in the current `ref`.

I thought of always checking out the `tests` folder before running the npm test, but I am not sure if this is the right way to automate running unit tests before pushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pre-receive` hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6/Documentation/githooks.txt#L227-L235) is invoked... just *before* starting to update refs on the remote repository.

So your files won't reflect what you have pushed.

You should push to an intermediate "gate" repository, where a `post-receveive` hook would:

- run the test
- push to the actual target repository if they pass
- send an email back and reset the target branch if they fail

Comment: Let me make sure I get it correctly, I should 
`git --work-tree=${WORKING_DIR}/build --git-dir=${GIT_DIR} checkout ${BRANCH} -f` 
then I run tests in `build` directory, if it pass I remove build and push to the `${WORKING_DIR}` root?

Comment: @AliElKhateeb That could be an implementation of that concept, yes: an intermediate step. But I am not sure this will checkout the right content, if done at the pre-receive hook level.